# ADF-SQL server untrusted domain

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, data-ingestion, azure-adf

I am trying to do a lookup from a sql server table. I am able to connect to the sql server instance via MSSQL management studio, but in ADF I get the below error.

> Cannot connect to SQL Database: '****', Database: '****', User:
> '****'. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make
> sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to
> access. Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot
> be used with Integrated authentication.,
> SqlErrorNumber=18452,Class=14,State=1, Activity ID:
> cd443ae3-b583-4c2f-87af-36013c3cefd9

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot connect to SQL Database: '', Database: '', User: '****'. Check
> the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL
> Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access. Login
> failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with
> Integrated authentication., SqlErrorNumber=18452,Class=14,State=1,
> Activity ID: cd443ae3-b583-4c2f-87af-36013c3cefd9

I got the same error I followed this [**Article**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-create-server-level-portal-quickstart?view=azuresql#create-a-server-level-ip-firewall-rule).it's working fine, some times errors may appear because of [**self-hosted IR**](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5812/connect-to-onpremises-data-in-azure-data-factory-with-the-selfhosted-integration-runtime-part-1/).

[image: Ref1]

I just added ***SQL database firewall rules*** and added ***client IP*** and allow ***Azure services*** and resources to access this server on the portal.

Please follow the below **reference**:

[image: Ref3]

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-create-server-level-portal-quickstart?view=azuresql#create-a-server-level-ip-firewall-rule

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5812/connect-to-onpremises-data-in-azure-data-factory-with-the-selfhosted-integration-runtime-part-1/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgDn14hxsTM&t=1421s

Comment: Hey @dragonachu, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot.  [Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers "https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers")